Extract html table with pagination. The URL doesnt change when changing pages
I want to extract the table as attached form this link: https://www.rfi.it/en/stations.html.
But I can extract the data from page 1. I need to extract the data of all pages.
Can you guys help me? Thanks
I'm not familiar with coding so I used github copilot, but it could not help me. Here it code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Initialize WebDriver with the correct path to your Edge WebDriver executable
service = Service('D:/Downloads/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)

# Navigate to the URL
url = 'https://www.rfi.it/it/stazioni.html'
driver.get(url)

# Accept cookies if the popup appears
try:
    accept_cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Accetta tutti i cookie")]'))
    )
    accept_cookies_button.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"No cookies button found or unable to click it. Error: {e}")

# Wait for the LISTA tab to be clickable and click it using JavaScript
lista_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(), "LISTA")]'))
)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lista_tab)

# Initialize variables
data = []
max_pages = 5  # Set the maximum number of pages to scrape
current_page = 1

while current_page <= max_pages:
    print(f"Processing page {current_page}")
    
    # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    
    # Find the table element
    table = soup.find('table', class_='table table-striped table-hover')
    
    # Check if the table exists
    if table:
        headers = [header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th')]
        print(f"Headers: {headers}")  # Debugging statement
        if current_page == 1:
            data.append(headers)  # Add headers only once
        
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            if cols:  # Ensure the row has columns
                cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
                print(f"Row data: {cols}")  # Debugging statement
                data.append(cols)
    else:
        print(f"No table found on page {current_page}. Stopping.")
        break
    
    # Find the "successivi" button and click it
    try:
        next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "pagination--next-btn")]'))
        )
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the page to load
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"No more pages or unable to find the next button. Stopping. Error: {e}")
        break
    
    # Increment the page counter
    current_page += 1

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()

# Create a DataFrame from the list of data
if data:
    print(f"Data collected: {data}")  # Debugging statement
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])  # Use the first row as header
    df = df.dropna(how='all')  # Drop rows where all elements are NaN
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame()

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)

The result is always: No more pages or unable to find the next button. Stopping. Error: Message:
Data collected: [['Stazione', 'Indirizzo', 'Comune', 'Provincia', 'Classificazione'], ['Abano Terme', 'Via Della Stazione, 10', 'Abano Terme'.... (page 1 of the table)

The result always: No more pages or unable to find the next button. Stopping. Error: Message: That's the whole error?  There's nothing after "Message:" ?

I'm not familiar with coding  This seems like a complicated task for a non-programmer...

It seems the provided next_button_xpath is wrong. try /html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]

I use python for data analysis and network analysis but I'm not really a programmer. I just learn basic things to serve my jobs.

Here's how to get the same data that is in the table, without selenium or pagination:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import gzip
import base64
import json

response = requests.get('https://www.rfi.it/it/stazioni.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

b64_data = soup.select_one('input#agendaEvents').get('data-agenda')
decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(b64_data)  
decompressed_bytes = gzip.decompress(decoded_bytes)
data = json.loads(decompressed_bytes.decode('utf-8'))

print(data)

it also has the same order as the site:
# print(data[0])
{
   "StationLink": "/it/stazioni/abano-terme.html",
   "StationName": "Abano Terme",
   "StationMunicipality": "Abano Terme",
   "StationAddress": "Via Della Stazione, 10",
   "StationProvince": "Padova",
   "prm": "false",
   "StationManagingAuthority": "",
   "StationMetalli": "Bronze",
   "StationRegion": "Veneto"
}


The data you're looking for is embedded within the HTML page, so no pagination is necessary:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://www.rfi.it/en/stations.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("#stationsJSON")["value"]
data = json.loads(data)

# pretty print the data:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

Prints:
[
    {
        "name": "Borgo S.Martino",
        "loc": {
            "n": 1,
            "add": "Via Stazione, 3",
            "lat": "45.0871605076522",
            "lng": "8.5207003862554007",
            "acc": false
        },
        "pr": "al",
        "rg": "piemonte",
        "ct": "Borgo San Martino",
        "lk": "borgo-s-martino.html"
    },
    {
        "name": "Funo Centergross",
        "loc": {
            "n": 2,
            "add": "Strada Provinciale Galliera",
            "lat": "44.5929334611169",
            "lng": "11.370742907462899",
            "acc": false
        },
        "pr": "bo",
        "rg": "emilia romagna",
        "ct": "Argelato",
        "lk": "funo-centergross.html"
    },

...


Don't complicate things. First of all, you need to examine the HTML page and the requests it sends. In this case, when you click the button, no request is sent, which means the data from the table is stored somewhere on the page, specifically in the input tag with the id stationsJSON, and you just need to extract it from there.
Here's a simple code:
import re
import json
import html
import requests

url = "https://www.rfi.it/en/stations.html"
pattern = re.compile(r'stationsJSON.+?(?:value=")([^"]+)', re.M)

if match := pattern.search(requests.get(url).text):
    data = json.loads(html.unescape(match.group(1)))
    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

